# if array element not present in a file need to print that as array element as zero

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

consider a array element :

```
args=("a" "b" "c")
```

now i need to check the array element in a file .
consider the file as :

`file`:

```
a 10


c 30
```

`grep ${args[@]/#/-e } file`

Output:

```
a 10


c 30
```

Expected Output:

```
a 10


b 0


c 30
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an option in grep to print a string if the no matches are found.

I would do this with below script:

```
for i in ${args[@]}; do
    grep $i file.txt
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo $i"  0"
    fi
done
```

Comment: You could make this more concise with `grep $i file.txt || echo $i 0`.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk` and `process substitution` this is much simpler:

```
args=("a" "b" "c")

awk 'FNR==NR{a[$1]=$0; next} {
     print ($1 in a) ? a[$1] : $1, 0}' file <(printf "%s\n" "${args[@]}")

a 10
b 0
c 30
```

Comment: i have  a doubt consider my array elements has 155 elements its failing yet..

It has many lines i cant add all things in comments . how can i get help ???

Comment: What is the error you are getting with your 155 element array? You can upload your data on pastebin.com and provide link here